# Converting lambda to normal def function

Tags: python, function, lambda

I am a beginner programmer and I'm currently watching Bro Code's tutorial on Python.
He coded it like this:

[image]

I was wondering how you would do it with a "def" instead of a lambda and I guess I should put it in the next part.

I tried doing this:

```
students = [("ab", "F", 60),
            ("man", "D", 21),
            ("yo", "A", 22),
            ("pope", "C", 32)]
def age(x):
    return students.index(2)
a = sorted(students, key=age, reverse=True)

for e in a:
    print(e)
```

of course it didn't work and now i'm stuck.

edit:
in the middle of writing this i got what i should've done and now i don't understand it.

```
def age(x):
    x = x[2]
    return x
```

if someone could explain it to me it would be great, thanks anyways

Comment: you are reasigning value of x [2] to x ,  it is  equivalent to `x=[1,2,34] tmp =x[2] x = tmp`

Comment: What do you not understand? The assignment to `x` isn't necessary; you can simply write `def age(x): return x[2]`. The main difference is that a lambda expression consist of a *single* expression to use as the return value, so no `return` keyword is needed to indicate which expression should be used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `.index()` function does the inverse of what you wanted. Given a list

```
x = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
```

if you did

```
print(x.index("a"))
```

you will see the answer

```
> 0
```

Because "a" is the 0th index in the list. The next function you tried and succeeded with was

```
print(x[0])

> "a"
```

which returns the value at that index in the list.

As an aside, as others have mentioned, you don't need to assign it to x, your function could just be

```
def age(x):
    return x[2]
```

Comment: ah, I see what I did wrong. I thought index as a function works both ways, so it can print the value upon input of an index and vice versa. 
for example: 
```
a = [a,b,c,d]
a.index(0)
>a
```
thanks for clearing that for me 
basically i didn't know i had to do "a[0]" to get the value at index 0.

Answer (score 0):

The following are equivalent to a first approximation:

```
f = lambda x: RETURN_VALUE

def f(x):
    return RETURN_VALUE
```

The only significant difference is that `f.__name__` is `<lambda>` in the first case, `f` in the second.

In other words, any function that can be defined with a single `return` statement can be defined with a lambda expression, and vice versa. The body of the lambda expression is just the return statement minus the `return` keyword.

Comment: why did index() not work? is the "key" argument already an index? that's the part i didn't understand, i don't understand what x[2] means0. thank you all for the replies i'm not that good at english also so sorry haha

Comment: The key argument is just a function that gets applied to a value in the list. `index` returns the index where a given value is found, such that `d[d.index(x)] == x`. (Since `index` finds the *first* occurrence, it's not necessarily true that `d.index(d[k]) == k`.)

Comment: `('a', 'b', 'c')[2] == 'c'`.